# createScaledBitmap resize to -1

Tags: android

i want resize image before i place it in ImageView but after use **createScaledBitmap**
image get height and widht set to -1

sample

```
int screenWidth =  activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
int imageWidth = loadedImage.getWidth();
float ratio = (float) screenWidth / imageWidth;
float newHeight = loadedImage.getHeight()*ratio;
loadedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(loadedImage, screenWidth, (int) newHeight, false);
```

after that fields mHeight and mWidht in debugger show -1 values. why.?

edit: `acticity` is passed in constructor

Comment: where did you define and use fields `mHeight` and `mWidht`?

Comment: When are you calling this code?

Comment: @Neil in ArrayAdapter class `getView`